Adjectives derived from proper nouns are not always capitalized
I have had a hard time teaching the rule that proper adjectives are capitalized on the Continent (one student even proudly declaimed that proper adjectives just don't exist in England). I taught this as a categorical rule, but today I came across this.
A rule that the EU published concerning its publications:

Adjectives derived from proper nouns. Not all adjectives derived from proper nouns take a capital:

french (chalk, polish, windows)
morocco (leather)
roman (type)


I have consulted the US authorities and proper adjectives are capitalized (with some exceptions like french fries, but I teach the rule categorically because French fries is permissible but french movie is not). Any other authorities weigh in on this?

What seems to be behind the examples quoted is that such adjectives are not capitalised when the connection with the proper noun from which they are derived is lost. When referring to roman type, practically nobody is likely to have any thoughts of Rome; on the other hand, most people do know that Roman Catholic Church is based in Rome. It is unlikely, however, that anybody will be able to produce a mechanically applicable rule separating the two kinds of cases.

@Lambie I agree, but this basic error is committed by a shocking number of my very well-educated students. To be honest, I haven't run across many students who use proper adjectives correctly, so I tell them to rephase if they are not sure...

Does this answer your question? Why is quixotic not Quixotic (a proper adjective)? See also Is the b in B/brussels sprouts capitalized? What about the f 's in F/french F/fries?.

Just as proper nouns may be genericised if much used (thus we can happily hoover (verbification thrown in for free) the carpet with a hoover , but must write with a Biro unless we want to be sued) ... so may proper adjectives. @jsw29's  final remark is true, and explains why even well educated Anglophones differ in usage.

I think the rule comes from the word "derived" -- if it actually refers to the proper noun, you capitalize it, but if it's just an idiom that originated from the noun and no longer has a direct association, you don't.

Note that "Roman Catholic Church" is a compound proper noun of its own (like "United States"), it's not using the word "Roman" as an adjective.

@Barmar I agree, but dictionaries do list French fries instead of french fries. I will continue to teach it as I do, because there are far too many blatant errors like: the german national soccer team and I am a londoner. Cheers!

In practice, a lot of these are found in both forms, and newly-formed adjectives will tend to be capitalized (so if you want to pick a random character and create an adjective from it, you'd capitalize) so capitalizing unless you know otherwise is probably a reasonable rule.

But regarding the loss of capital letters, this doesn't just apply to adjectives but also to nouns and verbs: hoover (noun and verb), morocco (noun), xerox (verb), french (verb), dutch (adverb)...
